# How to squeeze or reduce dimensions of a mapdataset in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dimensions

I have a mapdataset element with the following dimensions:

```
MapDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1, 24), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1, 24), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))
```

I want to create a functional api as below:

```
input_ = keras.layers.Input(shape=24)
hidden1 = keras.layers.Dense(30, activation="relu")(input_)
hidden2 = keras.layers.Dense(30, activation="relu")(hidden1)
concat = keras.layers.concatenate([input_, hidden2])
output = keras.layers.Dense(1)(concat)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input_], outputs=[output])
```

I get the following error

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_3" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 24), found shape=(None, 1, 24)
```

How can I reduce the dimensions in the map dataset? I tried `[:, -1:, :]` or the `tf.squeeze()` method but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just apply another `map` function to your dataset to reduce the dimensions, before feeding your dataset to your model:

```py
def prepare_data(x):
  return tf.random.normal((samples, 1, 24)), tf.random.normal((samples, 1, 24))

def reduce_dimension(x, y):
  return tf.squeeze(x, axis=1), tf.squeeze(y, axis=1)

samples = 50
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(samples)

dataset = dataset.map(prepare_data)
print('Before reducing dimension: ', dataset.element_spec)

dataset = dataset.map(reduce_dimension)
print('After reducing dimension: ', dataset.element_spec)
```

```
Before reducing dimension:  (TensorSpec(shape=(50, 1, 24), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(50, 1, 24), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))
After reducing dimension:  (TensorSpec(shape=(50, 24), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(50, 24), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))
```

Depending on your use case, you could also simply reduce the dimensions in the first `map` function. Here, I am assuming that your `MapDataset` already exists.